# Find maximum value in a list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm new to Python, and I've been stuck at one point for several days now.

There is a list of dicts like this one:

`dd = [{'prod': 'White', 'price': '80.496'}, {'prod': 'Blue', 'price': '9.718'}, {'prod': 'Green', 'price': '7161.3'}]`

I need to output the value in `prod` based on the maximum value of the `price`.

Here is the desired result:
`Green`

I have tried many ways based on information I found on SO:

```
dd = [{'prod': 'White', 'price': '80.496'}, {'prod': 'Blue', 'price': '9.718'}, {'prod': 'Green', 'price': '7161.3'}]
L = [v for v in dd if v['price']==max([u['price']for u in dd])][0]['prod']
print(L)
```

Output:
`Blue`

(Almost correct, but "Blue" does not have the maximum value of the `price`!)

```
dd = [{'prod': 'White', 'price': '80.496'}, {'prod': 'Blue', 'price': '9.718'}, {'prod': 'Green', 'price': '7161.3'}]
L = max(dd, key=lambda x:x['price'])
print(L)
```

Output:
`{'prod': 'Blue', 'price': '9.718'}`

```
dd = [{'prod': 'White', 'price': '80.496'}, {'prod': 'Blue', 'price': '9.718'}, {'prod': 'Green', 'price': '7161.3'}]
L = max(e['price'] for e in dd)
print(L)
```

Output:
`9.718`

```
from operator import itemgetter
dd = [{'prod': 'White', 'price': '80.496'}, {'prod': 'Blue', 'price': '9.718'}, {'prod': 'Green', 'price': '7161.3'}]
L = max(map(itemgetter('price'), dd))
print(L)
```

Output:
`9.718`

```
dd = [{'prod': 'White', 'price': '80.496'}, {'prod': 'Blue', 'price': '9.718'}, {'prod': 'Green', 'price': '7161.3'}]
seq = [x['price'] for x in dd]
L = max(seq)
print(L)
```

Output:
`9.718`

In all cases, the maximum value is 9.718 and not 7161.3. How can I fix this? I'm using MS Visual Studio running Python 3.9.

Comment: `"9.718"` is greater than `"7161.3"` for the same reason `"two"` is greater than `"four"` -- strings are compared lexographically (alphabetically, except it's not just for letters of the alphabet).  You need to convert those strings to numbers (`float`s in this case) if you want to compare them numerically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the price values to floats for the `key` parameter:

```py
max(dd, key=lambda x: float(x['price']))['prod']
```

This outputs:

```py
Green
```

Comment: Is this right?
 `L = max(dd, key=lambda x: float(x['price']))['prod']`
I got: `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: oh, sorry)) I accidentally put an extra `'` symbol in the code above. Thank you!